# The required DLLs in a visual studio c++ project

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2012, dll, settings

I've done some searching and seen questions similar in nature to mine, but none that quite hit the nail on the head of the issue I'm having.

I'm making C++ game in Visual Studio (with the Allegro 5 library) and encountering difficulty running it on other computers. I'm well aware of the 'MSVCR##.dll is missing from this computer' issue, but what I'm wondering is why I'm unable to run my Release build because I'm missing the MSVCR##'D'.dll on a certain computer, when I was under the impression that the 'D' suffixed .dll was exclusively required for running the debugger. I've checked in my configuration manager for release build settings and I have 'Generate Debug Info' set to No, which I thought was the only thing I needed to do. My question I guess is whether or not there are any other settings I need to configure to make sure my Release build isn't looking for the MSVCR##D.dll. Thanks in advance anyone who has any info!

Comment: Is the Allegro library using MSVCR as well, and are you maybe linking to a debug build of the library? Btw, it is perfectly OK to `Generate Debug Info` in release builds, in fact recommended (as external PDBs). What you must _not_ do is #define _DEBUG, or compile with `/MDd` instead of `/MD`.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick reply! So I'm definitely using Multi-threaded DLL (/MD) as the Runtime Library setting, but I'm not sure how to check if Allegro uses MSVCR.

Comment: This is the first time I've tried to put together a large scale game project in C++ so I'm probably asking some really obvious questions!

Comment: I don't really know about Allegro. Did you build it from sources, or used some prebuilt binaries? If the former, check the build settings of Allegro itself, and also doublecheck the library you link against. Otherwise, use [Dependency Walker (depends.exe)](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to try and figure out where the MSVCR##D dependency comes from.

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio 2015... Then install allegro through NuGet, that way all dependencies and dlls and libs will be managed for you automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You're a bit confused about the use of the *D libraries. They're indeed used for debug builds, but debug builds differ in multiple ways from release builds. For starters, debug builds by default come with a *.PDB file that contains all the function names (This is your "Generate Debug Info" option). A debugger looks into the .PDB file to find a readable name for a crash site.

Another debug option is to not inline code - this keeps your named functions intact. Inlining may put that single finction inside three other functions, which complicates debugging a bit.

Finally the Debug CRT includes functions that perform extra error checking against bad arguments. Many functions exhibit Undefined Behavior when passed a null pointer, for instance. The Debug libraries will catch quite a few of those, whereas the Release versions assume you pass valid pointers only.

Now DLL's can reference each other; there's a whoel dependency graph. That's why the Dependency Walker tool exists: it figures out which DLL's rqeuire which other DLL's, and this will tell you why you need the *D version.

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate the extra detail here. I'll be hitting up Dependency Walker shortly to see where exactly I'm requiring the *D version. I think I'm getting quite a few bugs in my Release build actually that are due to the lack of that extra error checking you were talking about, so figuring out exactly where those are coming from is going to be quite the project!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much for all your inputs, I was able to learn a fair bit from this. It turns out the issue was (of course) entirely my fault, as when setting up the Allegro 5 dependencies in the project settings (under General->Linker) I was accidentally including a dependency for the debug version of the Allegro monolith-md.dll as well as the non-debug version in my Release build, and that .dll was in turn referencing the *D version of the MSVCR .dll. The issue has been resolved by removing that dependency from the Release build of my game.

Answer (score 0):

Install dependency walker on that machine. Load the exe. Check if any of the dependent dlls are missing.